# Google Maps Not Showing On Android Device.

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So my problem is that the google maps is not showing on my android device which is using 3.2 API

I've already tried to do most of not all the suggestions I found online while searching for a solution to this problem.

I do have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in my manifest.

I've followed the google written procedure to produce a signed key (http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#setup) and obtained said key and put it in the layout `android:apiKey="0R8lbu8yQL1Wgw-13s5sUBXZXusi4mEY3EhqWWw"` And still I see gray tiles instead of the map.

I know that the debug key works on AVD but not on the android device whereas the signed key is supposed to work on the device and not in the AVD.

I'm willing to try another step by step procedure to make this work and if it does I'll be forever grateful.

Please help! Thank you!

**SOLUTION:**

Was installing the wrong apk to device. Had to do:

`adb install <your-file-name>.apk`

in the console

**EDIT:**

`Manifest File`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.googlemaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>



<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >

    </activity>


    <service
      android:name=".WorldWideMapService"
      android:process=":remote">
      <intent-filter>
        <action
          android:name="com.example.googlemaps.WorldWideMapService" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to correct you regarding application sign, and map api key.

There is no such thing, like default api key would work with avd only, not with device. Thing is, map api key is associated with Signature KeyStore, by which application being signed, so If you are signing application with Default Key, then you should use default api key. However If you are signing application with your own keystore you should register new keystore to google map api, and get an api key. To upload on Google play we need application is to be signed with some other keystore than default keystore, so there we need to get an release map api key.

In your case, I think, you are signing your app with default keystore, whereas, using map api key of different store.

and yes, Problem might be as @Raju mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by default api key. Do you mean the debug api key that I mentioned? I've tried using that key then running the app on the android device and I still get grey tiles.

I've tried exporting, signing, creating my own keystore to get a new api key which I've used and still get grey tiles.

Comment: Create map api key for your application keystore..and use that in your application after done this generate apk file and install in your device it will works defenetly.

Comment: Wait so generate the apk file after putting in the map api key. Where do I save the apk file? In the bin folder?

Comment: Select android tools-> export signed application package and then select any folder you want to store the signed apk.

Comment: How will the application know to use that generated apk file? I already have one similarly named in the bin folder.

Comment: you need to install the apk. and installing apk, you need to go to the directory to which you exported signed apk, then execute adb install apkname.apk in console.

Comment: Well! There was the problem. I was installing the wrong apk. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Add this one in manifest file before activity and inside application tag

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: Did that and still getting gray tiles.

Comment: follow this one to get map key https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey

Comment: I've tried that, but I'll take a stab at it again. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: OK. So it's the exact same key as the one I'm currently using. 0R8lbu8yQL1Wgw-13s5sUBXZXusi4mEY3EhqWWw. Maybe I screwed up when creating the keystore?